# MATLAB: DLL loaded by mex would not unload?

Tags: dll, matlab, mex

I have a mex module called `p.mexw64` which uses another dll called `p.dll`
The mex module loads `p.dll` when it is loaded since it is linking to it's lib file.
Normally, when I want to recompile `p.dll` I do `clear p;`. This unloads `p.mexw64` and then in turn also unloads `p.dll`.

Except when it doesn't. In some scenario which I can't really quantify `p.mexw64` is unloaded (I see that it is in Process Explorer) but `p.dll` remain loaded and is not freed.
Then I'm forced to close matlab in order to recompile `d.dll` which is a pain.

What could possibly make this dll remain loaded after the mex which used it is gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `clear all`. Otherwise as a general solution, I find [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) an invaluable tool for Windows.

Comment: Unlocker can only unlock windows handles, not DLLs.

Comment: Actually it does. Did it not work for you? I just noticed that you are using a 64-bit version of Windows